# variable in mathematics vs variable in statistics

Tags: statistics, soft-question, definition

I was wondering about the difference between a variable in mathematics and a variable in statistics.

In mathematics, a variable is defined as a symbol that can represent different values.

Example: In the expression $x + 3$, $x$ is a variable. This means that $x$ is an empty symbol that doesn't mean anything. However, $x$ can be made to equal different numbers. When we say $x = 2$, we are asserting that $x$ symbolizes $2$. Consequently, $x + 3 = 5$.

In statistics, a variable is defined as a characteristic. I understand a characteristic as a label that we assign to a quantity. I understand a quantity as a number or a number with a unit.

Example: 3 feet is a quantity. Height is a label that we give to this quantity. Height is a characteristic. Height is also a variable.

In my mind, these definitions for variables seem different. Am I thinking about them wrong?

Comment: The term "random variable" has a specific meaning in statistics. Other than that there is no reason to believe variable means any different in Stats than in Maths. Not sure what the source of your confusion is

Comment: I understand that random variable is something different. So are the definitions "a symbol that represents different values" and "a characteristic" equivalent?

Comment: You seem to be using "empty variable" and "characteristic" in some special way that I do not understand.  If $x$ is your height in metres and $y$ is your height in centimetres then clearly $y = 100 \times x$.  Is this mathematics or statistics? Is $x$ an empty variable or a characteristic?

Comment: I guess I may just be misunderstanding the concept of a variable in general, which may be the source of my confusion. So we say: $x$ is your height in meters. "your height in meters" varies from person to person. Since $x$ just represents whatever "your height in meters" means, then $x$ varies from person to person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the Merriam-Webster definition of variable:

> 1a: a quantity that may assume any one of a set of values
>
> b: a symbol representing a variable

We can see that "variable" in mathematics and "variable" in statistics, in the way described in your question, actually correspond to different part of this definition. Height is a variable, in the sense that it is a quantity that can take several possible values. $x$ is a symbol representing a variable, and of course that variable could very well be a height.

But just to be clear, both parts of the definition are used in math and stats. In algebra, $x$ can be just a symbol, but in a particular problem it can represent a specific quantity. Similarly, in statistics, instead of talking of a specific variable such as height, we may want to be as general as possible and therefore represent it by a symbol such as $x$.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So this is my understanding now. Numbers like 2, 5, 8, and 3 are quantities. Now consider $x$. We will define $x$ as pointing to some number on the number line. One extra addition we will make is that this number changes from time to time. So $x$ points to different numbers. What $x$ represents is a changing quantity. What $x$ represents (the changing quantity) is a variable. We can also call the symbol $x$ itself a variable too, but here we are using the term "variable" in a slighly different sense.